# How pkg-config decides which look up path to add by default?

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, vala, pkg-config

I'm trying to run `pkg-config` on my 64bits elementary (ubuntu 14.04) from a .net gui application and it says that it doesn't find my packages that are found when I run the exact command from a terminal.

For reference, here's the command:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs  glib-2.0 gobject-2.0
```

Using the `PKG_CONFIG_DEBUG_SPEW` I managed to get detailed debug info for pkg-config and it looks like it initializes itself differently in the two cases.

Initialization in .net gui application:

```
Adding directory '/usr/share/pkgconfig' from PKG_CONFIG_PATH
Adding directory '/usr/lib/pkgconfig' from PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Initialization in terminal:

```
Adding directory '/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig' from PKG_CONFIG_PATH
Adding directory '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig' from PKG_CONFIG_PATH
Adding directory '/usr/local/share/pkgconfig' from PKG_CONFIG_PATH
Adding directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig' from PKG_CONFIG_PATH
Adding directory '/usr/lib/pkgconfig' from PKG_CONFIG_PATH
Adding directory '/usr/share/pkgconfig' from PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Of course my libraries are defined in the missing directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig' that is not added in the .net gui application.

**Why are the two initializations different?**

**How can I tell pkg-config to initialize the same it does in the terminal?**

> Note: I know that I can set the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` before calling pkg-config but I would prefer a simpler solution if available.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I know that I can set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH before calling pkg-config but I would prefer a simpler solution if available.

Nope, that's how to do it.  That said, both `/usr/share/pkgconfig` and `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` are in your search path already, so I'm not sure what you hope to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand why I would need to set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` when  call `pkg-config` from my .net applications while everything works fine launched from a terminal.

Comment: Like I said, pkg-config when called from your application is already searching both paths that it searches in the command line, so you don't.  However, setting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable is the answer to your question ("How pkg-config decides which look up path to add by default?").  It sounds like you're asking the wrong question, but you don't provide enough information to know what the problem really is.

Comment: As a side-reader, the question "How pkg-config decides which look up path to add by default?" I read as "How do I know what paths are included and what ones not? What determines whether a path is in the list?". The manual does not mention any specific directories, so it's a legitimate question to ask for anybody who has to deal with `.pc` files.